# APOSTROPHE inside xml element value

Tags: sql, xml

How Should I write an elements value inside an XML which contains apostrophe? Is there an escape sequence for the same?

I am dynamically getting an xml, something like this from a sql Select. Now in this case emp_name O''DELL, SEAN in itself contains apostrophe. How should I be getting emp_name so a proper xml could be formed?

```
<Result type="Benefit" emp_id='332' emp_name='O''DELL, SEAN '/>
```

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `&apos;` in place of '. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters).

Comment: Both of the answers worked. I came to know that &apos is escape sequence for apostrophe in XML. But how come &#39 is working too. I know that 39 is dec ascii value for apostrophe, but how is that related with XML. Does all the acii value sets work for xml too? Thanks.

Comment: UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII (ASCII being in actuality a 7-bit value, so 0-127), so if your XML is UTF-8 encoded decimal values up to 127 will work as escape sequences also. Beyond that, you're not ACSCII any more and the active code page comes into play for interpreting non-Unicode values.

Comment: DaveE - that's a very misleading comment. The numbers in numeric character references like &#39 are unicode codepoint values, and they have nothing to do with the character encoding used for the file. Apostrophe is &#39 even if the document is in EBCDIC.